# Loop sum in ColdFusion

Tags: loops, coldfusion, sum

I have this output:

```
<cfoutput>#TLFormat((get_ship_row.price[1]*get_ship_row.amount[1])+(get_ship_row.price[2]*get_ship_row.amount[2]))#</cfoutput>
```

As you can see I manually added two expressions that are defined by id 1 and 2. All I want is to create a loop of these numbers that will be inserted in this script, so that it will be easier to implement the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are getting a little convoluted - but it is hard to say without seeing more of your code. Also is `TLFormat()` a custom function of yours?

However, if you are looping over a query then this might work for you:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#get_ship_row.recordCount - 1#" index="i">
    #TLFormat((get_ship_row.price[i]*get_ship_row.amount[i]) + (get_ship_row.price[i+1]*get_ship_row.amount[i+1]))#
</cfloop>
```

I hope I understood your question correctly.